# Randomly select number (without repetition) for each group in R

Tags: r, random, dataset

I have the following dataframe containing a variable "group" and a variable "number of elements per group"

```
group    elements
1        3
2        1
3        14
4        10
..       ..
..       ..
30       5
```

then I have a bunch of numbers going from 1 to (let's say) 30

when summing "elements" I would get 900. what I want to obtain is to randomly select a number (from 0 to 30) from 1-30 and assign it to each group until I fill the number of elements for that group. Each of those should appear 30 times in total.

thus, for group 1, I want to randomly select 3 number from 0 to 30
for group 2, 1 number from 0 to 30 etc. until I filled all of the groups.

the final table should look like this:

```
group     number(randomly selected)
1           7
1           20
1           7
2           4
3           21
3           20
...
```

any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: why can't we just select `n` numbers from 0 to 30 for all the groups at once?

Comment: "when summing "numb" I would get 900" - what is `numb` - it is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, if you have `df` like this...

```
df
  group elements
     1        3
     2        1
     3       14
```

Then you can do this...

```
data.frame(group = rep(df$group,                     #repeat group no...
                       df$elements),                 #elements times
           number = unlist(sapply(df$elements,       #for each elements...
                                  sample.int,        #...sample <elements> numbers
                                  n=30,              #from 1 to 30
                                  replace = FALSE))) #without duplicates

   group number
1      1     19
2      1     15
3      1     28
4      2     15
5      3     20
6      3     18
7      3     27
8      3     10
9      3     23
10     3     12
11     3     25
12     3     11
13     3     14
14     3     13
15     3     16
16     3     26
17     3     22
18     3      7
```

Comment: Hi in reality I want duplicates up to 30 (each of the numbers should appear 30 times) and I have 30 groups for which the total number of elements is 900 (30 x 30)

Comment: In that case you could just do `number = sample(rep(1:30, 30))` in the above, which will produce a vector of length 900, being a random shuffle of 30 repetitions of 1:30 (ignoring the `group`).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
df <- read.table(text = "group    elements
1        3
2        1
3        14
4        10
30       5", header = TRUE)

# reproducibility
set.seed(1)
df_split2 <- do.call("rbind", 
                     (lapply(split(df, df$group),
                             function(m) cbind(m, 
                                               `number(randomly selected)` = 
                                                 sample(1:30, replace = TRUE, 
                                                        size = m$elements),
                                               row.names = NULL
                                        ))))

# remove element column name
df_split2$elements <- NULL
head(df_split2)
#>     group number(randomly selected)
#> 1.1     1                        25
#> 1.2     1                         4
#> 1.3     1                         7
#> 2       2                         1
#> 3.1     3                         2
#> 3.2     3                        29
```

The `split` function splits the `df` into chunks based on the `group` column. We then take those smaller data frames and add a column to them by sampling `1:30` a total of `elements` time. We then `do.call` on this list to `rbind` back together.

Comment: Not sure if you want repetition in the results or not. Your question states you don't but your example has two 7s in group 1. To remove repetition, you can just change the `replace = TRUE` to `replace = FALSE` in the call to `sample`.

Comment: I mean without repeating the number more than 30 times each. each of the numbers should be sampled 30 times in total

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to generate a new dataframe repeating $group $element times, and then using sample you can generate the exact number of random numbers:

```
data<-data.frame(group=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 elements=c(2,5,2,1,3))

data.elements<-data.frame(group=rep(data$group,data$elements),
                          number=sample(1:30,sum(data$elements)))
```

The result:

```
group number
1      1      9
2      1      4
3      2     29
4      2     28
5      2     18
6      2      7
7      2     25
8      3     17
9      3     22
10     4      5
11     5      3
12     5      8
13     5     26
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follow:

```
random_sample <- rep(1:30, each=30)
random_sample <- sample(random_sample)
```

then I create a df with this variable and a variable containing one group per row repeated by the number of elements in the group itself